# Cross-platform transparent windows in C++?

Tags: c++, cross-platform, transparency

I'm wondering how to make a window transparent, not cutout holes or the same transparency overall.

Well, just say I want to slap a PNG image of a rose or something and have it blend nicely with stuff behind and allow stuff behind to redraw and have their changes shine through the transparent parts of the picture/window.

I could (or would like to) use something like wxWidgets or OpenGL. But rather not Qt or GTK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that it's actually pretty simple to throw up a transparent picture on the screen using wxW:

```
wxScreenDC dc;

wxBitmap bmp(wxT("test.png"), wxBITMAP_TYPE_PNG);
dc.DrawBitmap(bmp, 250, 100, true);
```

Now I has to find out how to handle updates and such, it has to be ( maybe partially redrawn ) when something beneath updates.

As it is right now it just redraws itself ontop of itself, making it become fully opacue in a while.

There was another version of wxScreenDC::DrawBitmap that took a window as an argument, maybe it's that one solves this?

Answer (score 1):

How about using shaped frames?

```
wxBitmap m_bmp = wxBitmap(_T("redroseonwhite.png"), wxBITMAP_TYPE_PNG);
SetSize(wxSize(m_bmp.GetWidth(), m_bmp.GetHeight()));
wxRegion region(m_bmp, *wxWHITE);
bool m_hasShape = SetShape(region);
```

Look *wxWidgets-2.9.0\samples\shaped* for the full example.

Comment: I'm just curious, doesn't the edges get jagged? ( Alias problem )

Right now I feel like I've to do it completely myself, checking out how to do it on each platform I want to support ( X-server composite extension on X, whatever on windows, etc. )

Answer (score 0):

See [wxTopLevelWindow::SetTransparent](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_top_level_window.html#8e37aff45a001a83ff49745298a6978e).

> If the platform supports it will set the window to be translucent.

So I guess wxWidgets can do it.

Comment: I knew about that function, it sets the whole window to the same transparency. Not really what I meant.

I wants to have some pixels fully transparent, some others fully opacue and many others to be somewhere in between.

Like this random pic from the web (searched for "redrose.png" at google):
http://www.uniqueboutiquedallas.com/images/redrose.png

it's edges is transparent and makes it blend in with whatever is behind.

Look at http://www.rainlendar.net/cms/components/com_rny_gallery/simpleviewer/images/Skins-Win.png and you see how the windows are transparent on some portions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to do something other than C++, there may be other cross platform options like [JavaFx](http://javafx.com/samples/TransparentWindow/index.html) and [Adobe AIR](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/quickstart/creating_transparent_window.html).

Comment: I personally ( Really much ) dislikes them both. So no, is the simple answer.

Comment: Adobe Air is even less cross-platform today as they have dropped support for several platforms, inclusive my main platforms (Linux & Android).